# Is it possible to leverage HTML5 Canvas by making only a CSS change?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to see how I can make use of new visual effects in HTML5, while keeping the traditional HTML/JS/CSS separation of concerns.

Let's say I have a CSS file containing a theme for my application. I would like to enhance the theme so that it draws backgrounds and shapes dynamically using Canvas.

Obviously I am going to have to write JavaScript to do that, and include additional JS files. But can I:

1. use a CSS definition to include that JS, without changing existing HTML/JS code
2. associate Javascript drawing routines with a CSS selector

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you:

> - use a CSS definition to include that JS, without changing existing HTML/JS code
> - associate Javascript drawing routines with a CSS selector

No, you cannot control JS with CSS, but what you could do is run the JS, and based on looking at the attributes of a defined style, build conditions in your code. So if you look at an element, such as #menu, then you can look at which background colour is in use and run code accordingly.

Comment: Ok. So, if I want to make a "theme" that takes full advantage of everything that HTML5 offers, I need to include specific JS files, as well as CSS, in each page of my application. 

Thanks, that's what I thought.

Comment: It's no different that non HTML5 applications.